# Execute a file.bat with php

Tags: php, windows, shell, google-chrome

I have developed shell Windows code into a `.bat` file.
I want to run this file with PHP. I used:

```
$ output = shell_exec ('C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ node.bat');
```

The browser remains running but the script does not run.

When I click on the `file.bat` manmend everything is fine but I try to order by PHP

Comment: What's with the spaces in the file path?

Comment: The file.bat contains a command to execute a code node.js

Comment: Does the user you are running php/apache have sufficent permission to access the file and execute it?

Comment: Can you tell me how to close the cmd windows with a bash command?